# Tweepy Error: No __init__.py

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to install tweepy.
I get the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tweepy/__init__.py'
```

I looked in the tweepy folder and saw that indeed, there is no such file.

There was one **init**.py in the examples folder but it was completely blank (0 kb).

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are installing tweepy but the best way it would be to install it using pip(A tool for installing and managing Python packages).

```
pip install tweepy
```

If you don't have pip installed on your system you have a tutorial here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html